# Separating list of file and directory names

Tags: bash

Can one simplify or make clearer the following loop.  I loop through a sequence of file names and directories stored in `parg`, separating the valid names from the invalid ones.  I also remove duplicates.  `fdir` contains the valid entries, whereas `fda` and `dra` contain the valid files and valid directories respectively.

```
declare -A tag       # Prescribe an Associative Array
for fda in "${parg[@]}"; do
  [[ -f "$fda" ]] || [[ -d "$fda" ]] || continue  # Invalid Entry
  [[ ${tag[comint:${fda}]+E} ]] && continue       # Existing Entry
  tag[comint:${fda}]=1
  fdir+=( "$fda" )
  [[ -f "$fda" ]] && fla+=( "$fda" )
  [[ -d "$fda" ]] && dra+=( "$fda" )
done
```

Comment: This sounds like a pure programming question - pure programming questions usually are better suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: Just using better variable names will make this much clearer, but what constitutes "clearer" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: To me, it seems like you're asking for QA on your code - and in this case (as muru said), that's a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing your question:

> I have filenames and directory names (*some of which are duplicates
> and some others are nonexistent*) stored as elements in an
> array(*`original`*) ... In  `bash`, how can I test and process the
> elements in the `original` array into a new array `refined` excluding
> duplicate and nonexistent filenames/directory names ... And at the
> same time creating two new arrays `files`(*containing only refined
> filenames*) and `directories`(*containing only refined directory
> names*)?

Issue reproduction:

```bash
# Create some test files
$ touch file{1..3}

# Create some test directories
$ mkdir dir{1..3}

# List current working directory contents
$ printf '%s\n' *
dir1
dir2
dir3
file1
file2
file3

# Add contents to an array
$ for i in *
  do
  original+=( "$i" )
  done

# Add contents to the same array again to generate duplicates
$ for i in *
  do
  original+=( "$i" )
  done

# Add some invalid entries
$ original+=( "file4" "dir4" "file5" "dir5" )

# Print the array
$ printf '%s\n' "${original[@]}"
dir1
dir2
dir3
file1
file2
file3
dir1
dir2
dir3
file1
file2
file3
file4
dir4
file5
dir5
```

Possible solution:

```bash
# Test, refine and classify array items
$ for i in "${original[@]}"
  do
  if [[ ! "${refined[*]}" =~ "$i" ]]
    then
    [ -f "$i" ] && refined+=( "$i" ) && files+=( "$i" )
    [ -d "$i" ] && refined+=( "$i" ) && directories+=( "$i" )
    fi
  done

# Print the "refined" array
$ printf '%s\n' "${refined[@]}"
dir1
dir2
dir3
file1
file2
file3

# Print the "files" array
$ printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"
file1
file2
file3

# Print the "directories" array
$ printf '%s\n' "${directories[@]}"
dir1
dir2
dir3
```